# Metal entanglement puzzle with an S-shaped piece, chain, and rings

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

I lost the instructions and I’ve spent hours trying to identify it on the internet with no luck. It’s 3 rings with a metal chain with one removable ring. I’m stumped.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the objective is to separate the small ring from the chain. Also, it seems the chain goes around the S-shaped part twice. This procedure removes one of those loops, so you'll want to repeat it after you are done:

1. grab the bit of chain just above where it goes through the S-piece
2. pull all available slack to that part of the chain, make a loop out of the chain, and feed it through the nearest ring in the S-piece
3. loop the chain around the whole S-piece, and pull it back through the S-piece's ring

> [image]

This should entirely separate the chain from the S-piece, allowing the small ring to fall off the chain.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Bass. You are correct, the object is to remove the small ring from the chain. I’m experimenting with your solution but I’m still unable to remove one loop. This is probably operator error. I’ll keep trying and let you know if your solution worked.

Comment: After I replied I saw your illustration and that was the ticket. I actually ended up making 4 loops around the S-shape before I corrected it and completely removed the ring and chains. Thank you so much! Me and my kids have been trying to figure this out for a week and never thought about the small ring being in play. My daughter said it was impossible. :)

Comment: @Chuck glad that it worked! There should be checkmark icon on the left side of the answer, clicking it will "accept" the answer as being correct, which is how the site engine knows that an acceptable answer has been found. Happy puzzling!